# Codeigniter i18n - Hide default_controller language Segment in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, internationalization

Everything with my i18n library is perfect except 1 little issue:

I want to make 1 home page to choose a language with links (lead to: en, fr, bg, ...):

Example: `<a href="www.mysite.com/bg">BG</a>, <a href="www.mysite.com/en">EN</a>`

But always my default_uri is for an example: /bg and opens: **www.mysite.com/bg**

I want just to load plain URL up there as: **www.mysite.com**, load my START.PHP controller (no matter what name is, but not to be www.mysite.com/start) and after this to redirect with links to somewhere (bg/, en/, fr/)

Seems to be not so hard but don't know how to fix it

In MY_Lang.php:

```
// languages
    var $languages = array(
        'bg' => 'bulgarian',
        'en' => 'english',
        'fr' => 'french'
    );

    // special URIs (not localized)
    var $special = array (
        "admin", "start"
    );

    // where to redirect if no language in URI
    var $default_uri = '';
```

In my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "start";
$route['404_override'] = '';

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
//$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
//$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['^(bulgarian|english|french)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(bulgarian|english|french)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. For me the solution was that:

https://github.com/oleurud/Codeigniter_Multi-language_Package